# Possible to get a file descriptor for Python's StringIO?

Tags: python

From a Python script, I want to feed some small string data to a subprocess, but said subprocess non-negotiably accepts only a filename as an argument, which it will open and read. I non-negotiably do not want to write this data to disk - it should reside only in memory.

My first instinct was to use `StringIO`, but I realize that `StringIO` has no `fileno()`. `mmap(-1, ...)` also doesn't seem to create a file descriptor. With those off the table, I'm at a loss as to how to do this. Is this even achievable? The fd would be OS-level visible, but (I would expect) only to the process's children.

tl;dr how to create private file descriptor to a python string/memory that only a child process can see?

P.S. This is all on Linux and doesn't have to be portable in any way.

Comment: You could use a pipe?

Comment: Does the subprocess also insist on mmapping the file? If not, give it `/dev/stdin` as file name and feed the data to the subprocess's `stdin`.

Comment: Your Linux system surely has at least one tmpfs (RAMdisk) filesystem mounted - /tmp or /var/run, perhaps.  Write your file there, and everyone's happy.

Comment: @user4815162342 Thank you! I had no idea about /dev/stdin, and it worked exactly as I hoped via PIPE and Popen.communicate

Answer (score 2):

Reifying @user4815162342's comment as an answer:

The direct way to do this is:

- pass `/dev/stdin` as the file argument to the process;
- use `stdin=subprocess.PIPE`;
- finally, `Popen.communicate(<your input>)` to feed the desired contents