# Capture the output of subprocess.run() but also print it in real time?

Tags: python, subprocess

I would like to run a command using `subprocess.run()` and then get its stdout/stderr as a string, but I want the subprocess to also print its output to the console normally while running. If I do

```py
result = subprocess.run(['ls', '-al'])
```

then I can see the output printed to my console but I can't access the output after the command runs. If I do

```py
result = subprocess.run(['ls', '-al'], capture_output=True, text=True)
```

I can access `result.stdout` and `result.stderr` but nothing is printed to the console while the command is running. Can I have both printing to the console and saving to `result.stdout`?

Comment: Can you use `subprocess.Popen()` instead? Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417546/constantly-print-subprocess-output-while-process-is-running) can help?

Answer (score 4):

From the documentation of [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) :

> Run the command described by args. Wait for command to complete, then return a CompletedProcess instance.
> [...]
> If *capture_output* is true, stdout and stderr will be captured. When used, the internal Popen object is automatically created with `stdout=PIPE` and `stderr=PIPE`.

The docs for [`subprocess.PIPE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.PIPE) say :

> Special value that can be used as the *stdin*, *stdout* or *stderr* argument to [Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) and indicates that a pipe to the standard stream should be opened. Most useful with Popen.communicate().

The doc for the [Popen constructor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) parameter `stdout` :

> stdin, stdout and stderr specify the executed program’s standard input, standard output and standard error file handles, respectively. Valid values are PIPE, DEVNULL, an existing file descriptor (a positive integer), an existing [file object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object), and `None`.

So using `capture_output=True` is a no-go, because the output will be stored in a pipe for you to read **after** the call finishes.

The simpler is for you to use [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) as @MatBBastos suggested, with wich you can [`communicate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) (repeatedly sending content to *stdin* and receiving content from *stdout*/*stderr*). The [solution linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4417735/11384184) is a bit dated (cf its own comments; Python 2) but should work well. A related solution is this one.

To keep using `subprocess.run`, you will have to provide a *file descriptor* as `stdout` parameter, which **I don't know how** would have to redirect to a [file object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object) that does what you want : writing to the standard stream, but also keeping a copy in memory for later use.
There are docs in the [io](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html) module, and a lot of questions on Stack Overflow about doing things like that, but it is notably more difficult than the other way.

Comment: While it is possible in theory to implement a file object that would both write its content to stdout and keep a copy for later, it seems difficult ([cf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19409025/python-stringio-doesnt-work-as-file-with-subrpocess-call) and [cf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52340974/possible-to-get-a-file-descriptor-for-pythons-stringio)). It remints a bit of what [`tee`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command)) does, but I still don't know how to implement that. Using POpen.Communicate is still the way to go, althought cumbersome.